# Removing Spaces from Strings in Python 3.x

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need to transform the string:

```
"There are 6 spaces in this string."
```

to:

```
"Thereare6spacesinthisstring."
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `replace`

```
string = "There are 6 spaces in this string"
string = string.replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: LJ3: It's also considered A Good Thing to accept answers by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer, as well as up-vote answers you find useful

Answer (score 4):

```
new = "There are 6 spaces in this old_string.".replace(' ', '')
```

If you want to strip all whitespace, including tabs:

```
new = ''.join( old_string.split() )
```

Comment: wouldn't re.subn be better to handle whitespaces? or are the two equivalent?

Comment: Thanks had tried the replace version above with no luck, the join split solution is elegant and works like a charm... btw Python 3.2.3

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace() :

```
print(string.replace(" ", ""))
```

You can also delete white characters at the end / beginning (or both!) with rstrip, lstrip or strip.